I need to compare the categories and items in the one file with the master list and output the missing items for each category
I have two Excel files. The first one contains a list of 34 items that
serve as a master list. The second file is generated monthly and
contains two columns: one column with categories and the other with
items.
What I need to do is to check if every category in the second file
contains all 34 items from the master file. In other words, each
category should be associated with all 34 items, and if any item is
missing for a given category, I want to see which items are missing.
How can I use Power Query to achieve this? Specifically, I want to
create a check that compares the categories and items in the second
file with the master list, and then outputs the missing items per
category.
i have tried to merge the two tables to compare the values then used the Left Anti Join option. which was supposed to return only the rows from the second table that don’t have a match in the first table.

Can you please share some data?

pls provide some sample data and expected output

Once both excel files are imported into power query.
Merge Queries:
Select "Merge Queries" in the MonthlyData query.
Choose MasterList as the second table.
Match on the item column.
Use the "Left Anti Join" option.
This will create a new column that only contains items missing from each category.
Expand the Result:
Expand the merged column to reveal the missing items.
Group the Results:
Use "Group By" on the "Category" column.
Aggregate the missing items to get a list of missing items per category.
This was difficult to answer with little context so may not work but please let me know
